# Jquery ajax call will not complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function that is called on a button click. The function completes up to and including printing the dataString to the console, but the ajax call never completes. It just redirects to the same page with a blank GET query string. I've been looking at this for a long time and I can't figure out why. I apologize if I'm missing something simple, but other similar calls work exactly right and this one doesn't.

```
    $(document).on('click', '#addTreasure_btn', function(){

    var itemName = $("#treas_search").val();
    var qty = $("#numofitems").val();
    var tr_play = $("#play_search").val();
    var broken = $("input[id='treasbrok']").is(':checked');

    var dataString = "qty="+qty+"&itemName=" + itemName +"&tr_play=" + tr_play+"&broken="+broken+"&playerName="+player;

    console.log(dataString);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_treasure.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false
    });

});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the completion handler?

Comment: Why are you using the `type` keyword instead of `method`?

Comment: @z3nth10n jQuery allows type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed two things, first the success callback and the misstyped `type` variable declared.

You should do this as I will show you:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST", // Use method keyword instead of type.
    url: "add_treasure.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) { // Declare the success callback.
       alert("Something here!");
    }
});
```

If you want to add more parameters I'd recommend you to follow the following: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Hope this helps!

Comment: type="POST" is ok in jQuery

Comment: I saw it for first time. Sorry, I didn't know.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize the success part was required. I'll go back and re-read the documentation. Thank you for being patient and helping me learn.

Answer (score 2):

1. Assuming addTreasure_btn is a type=submit or at least NOT a type=button, you need to change to type=button or prevent the form/page from being submitted
2. You need a success and an error handler
   `data: dataString, 
   success: function(returndata) { console.log(returndata)},
   error: function(jxhr) { console.log(jxhr)},`

Alternatively do a $.post:

See the documentation: [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), 
[$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addTreasure_btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // in case you do not have type="button"
  var itemName = $("#treas_search").val();
  var qty = $("#numofitems").val();
  var tr_play = $("#play_search").val();
  var broken = $("input[id='treasbrok']").is(':checked');

  var dataString = "qty=" + qty + "&itemName=" + itemName + "&tr_play=" + tr_play + "&broken=" + broken + "&playerName=" + player;

  console.log(dataString);

  $.post("add_treasure.php", datastring, function(result) {
    console.log(result)
  });

});
```